# group by in mongoid/mongodb

Tags: mongodb, group-by, mongoid

Unit has_many StationInstances

StationInstance belongs_to unit

I want to group station instances by unit_id in mongoid.

What will be the query to get all the station instances grouped by unit_id?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this directly using [group](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Group) (which internally a map reduce)  method in mongo as you did in sql. the code  is

```
  db.StationInstance.group({key:{unit_id:true},
                            cond:{},
                            reduce:function(a,b){b.sum++;},
                            initial:{sum:0}});
```

this will return only the counts

```
>> [ { "unit_id" : xxxx, "sum" : 1 }, { "unit_id" : zzzzz, "sum" : 2 } ]
```

But you cannot get the StationInstance items along with it

Instead You can do this with MongoDB [map-reduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce).. check the below code

```
map = function() { 
    emit(this.unit_id,{count:1,StationInstance:this._id}); 
}
```

In map function you can group by unit_id of StationInstance (since it belongs to unit, it will have unit_id), and aggregating it by count. since plain count doesn't return the whole object ,we explicitly return the id (or whatever field or whole object by just `this` ) of the StationInstance

```
reduce = function(k, values) {
    var result = {count: 0, StationInstance: []};
    values.forEach(function(value) {
        result.count += value.count;
        result.StationInstance.push(value.StationInstance);
    });
    return result;
}
```

and in reduce we count the grouped item, and put the StationInstances into an array

finally issuing

```
 db.StationInstance.mapReduce(map,reduce,{out: { inline : 1}})
```

will return the desired result

to do this in [mongoid](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#map_reduce-instance_method),just `stringfiy` the functions map & reduce and use it like

```
StationInstance.collection.mapreduce(map,reduce,{:out => {:inline => 1},:raw=>true })
```

Comment: It worked with few adjustments. But not clear on what that `{:inline => 1 }` and `:raw => true` does?

Comment: @Millisami, inline is a output option for reduce, means it tells the mongo to perform in memory by not creting any temp collections, its suitable if the data is small. check the link for more info http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-Outputoptions

Comment: In the map function, we are emitting the `unit_id` as `emit(this.unit_id,{count:1,StationInstance:this._id});` What if, instead of the `this.unit_id`, I want to get the unit's title which is in `unit` document model?

Comment: @Millisami, i dont think  you can do that.. we are running map reduce on StationInstance,. it only got the unit_id stored because of mongoid belongs_to relation...